# React - Jest Mock an inner component

Tags: reactjs, mocking, components, jestjs

I have a component that has a child component.
This child component has some rules to display its children content, and I want to mock it to display the content regardless its rules.

```
import MediaQuery from './component.media.query'
class Dumb extends Component {   render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>Generic content</div>
        <MediaQuery device="DESKTOP">
          <div id="desktop">Specific desktop content</div>
        </MediaQuery>
      </Fragment>
    )   } }
```

I've tried some ways, and even the simplest is not working:

```
  describe('Dumb component', () => {
    jest.doMock('./component.media.query', () => {
      const Comp = () => <div id='desktop'>Mocked</div>
      return Comp
    })

    it('should display the desktop', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Dumb />)
      expect(wrapper.find('#desktop')).toExist()
    })
  })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to re-import Dumb module after mocking its dependency.

Comment: I've tried with no success:
    jest.mock('./component.media.query', () => () => 'MediaQuery')
    const Dumb = require('./component.dumb').default

Comment: I'd expect this approach to work but it's unclear what didn't work in your case. In the example you posted Dumb isn't exported at all.

Comment: were u guys able to find a solution to this?  I have the exact same isue

Answer (score 7):

In your test you can mock it like this :

```
jest.mock('./component.media.query', () => () => 'MediaQuery') 
//note that you have to enter the path relative to the test file.
```

With enzyme you can find the element like this

```
wrapper.find('MediaQuery')
```

Comment: what does it mean () => 'MediaQuery' ?

Comment: Its a function that return the string `MediaQuery`. Enzyme will render this as it would be a component with the same names: `<MediaQuery />`

Comment: What is the **component** is from a *node package* (external) rather than a *local* file?

Comment: What do you do when you have to return a mock component instead of returning `() => 'MediaQuery'`?